# '(single quote) character doesnot insert in to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I need to enter:

> your's faithfully

into the database but it does not insert into the database. I'm using php and mysql.
**

*I'm doesnt talking about sql injection. I want to insert '(single quote) into my mysql table field.*

If anyone already face this problem , please share...

Comment: Double it, e.g. `your''s faithfully` to get `your's faithfully`.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that *your's faithfully* is grammatically incorrect.  But yes, SQL Injection and all that jazz.

Comment: @chris85, ANSI SQL, I assume it works in MySQL too.

Comment: @jarlh yup, you are correct, worked on sqlfiddle.

Comment: @jarlh , i got the word(your's faithfully) from client android app. How to identify the particular word and tell me the logic to double the single quotes programatically from group of words.

Comment: @chris85 correct that it works but incorrect that it should be suggested like that with php...

Comment: @KavinD you don't, simple use prepared statement. Did u even bother to look at the link at the top of your question? It's right below where it says [`This question already has an answer here:`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: @Prix Thanks.. I got it..